# Run time optimisation Prime or Not

Tags: python

I was tasked to write a program that takes in an input as an integer. If the number is prime the program returns 1 and if the number is not prime the program returns the smallest divisor greater than 1.

```
def isPrime(n):
    if n > 1:
        for i in range (2,n):
            if (n % i) == 0 :
                return i 
    return 1
```

I'm trying to improve the run time of this code can i get some help please?

Comment: Remember that 2 is also a prime number.

Comment: You don't need to loop up to `n`. The square root of `n` is enough. (Edit: oh, two users with the same name)

Comment: Asking for code optimizations is off-topic here. You can try [codereview.se] but makes sure to check their help center before posting

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the same algorithm, one step you can take to improve the runtime is by optimizing your for loop so that it only checks to the square root of n:

```
def isPrime(n):
    if n > 1:
        for i in range (2,int(n ** .5) + 1):
            if (n % i) == 0 :
                return i 
    return 1
```

This will reduce the runtime of your algorithm from O(n) to O(sqrt(n))

Okay, since you asked for an explanation on why we should only check to the square root of n:

Let's say we have a number, 36. The factors of 36 are: `1,2,3,4,6,9,12,18,36`

In any case, if the factors of 36 are `a` and `b`, so that `a * b = 36` and `a < b`, this inequality will ALWAYS hold true:

`a <= sqrt(36) <= b`

This means that, if there are no factors of 36 from 2 all the way to the square root of n, no factors will exist that are greater than the square root of n.

The reason we check the square root as well is for numbers like 49, who have no factors other than its square root, 7. This is why we add 1 to the `int(n ** .5)`, because the conversion will round it down, which makes it not inclusive in the for loop.

Comment: Could you explain the part where it only checks the square root of n please